# Why couldn't the Time Lords get through?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord

Maybe I've got to watch the episode a few more times, but I don't understand why the Time Lords couldn't get through

> the tear in the fabric of space and time, unless the Doctor spoke his name. What stopped them?
>  Also, if there was something that stopped them, how come they DID manage to get through *just a little*, after Clara told them his name was The Doctor

.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### It *is* unclear, but it's more like they didn't know if they SHOULD return.

Gallifrey is stuck in another universe; they have no idea what's going on in ours, or even if the crack they'd found led to the right universe at all! They were basically knocking on the door and asking the Doctor if the bad guys have gone and it's safe to come out now.

> If I give my name, they'll know they found the right place... and that it's safe to come through.

Instead, Clara asked them to help the Doctor: that alone is enough reason for them to not come out of hiding. Rather they just poked through a bit of help to the Doctor out through the hole, in the hope that some time later he'll be able to give them the all-clear.

Comment: Nice. I think your edit nails it.